# Spring MVC - Tomcat return constant 404 errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just started Spring MVC with Maven and when I send a request Tomcat always returns a 404 not found result.
This is my simple controller with configuration files.

HelloController.java:

```
package com.mvcdemo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHelloWorld(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute(
                        "message",
                        "Hello World and Welcome to Spring MVC!");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-   app_3_0.xsd"
                 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

  <!-- FIXME    Change name of the package to your base-package -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.mvcdemo"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

</beans>
```

hello.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Is the problem located in bad configuration of the web.xml or spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml files that prevent the URL to be mapped?

Comment: Check with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73183528/9926179

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check what kind of version you have for Tomcat. If it's 10, you need to downgrade it to 9. Common case when having this error.

Comment: Spring-boot should ship with its own Tomcat, and that's the version you should use.